# Home Email Quick Edit not working - Version 5.9.0 wordpress 5.0.3

Tags: wordpress, contact-view, quickform

When you search for a contact and you select the contact.

if you select "add or edit email" on the "home email" it grows bigger and then shrinks to a single line which you cannot edit.

If you select the edit at the top of the contact you can edit it without any issues.

Just upgraded form version 4.7 (used to work with this version)

CiviCRM Version 5.9.0

Wordpress Version 5.0.3

CiviCRM » Search Results » View Contact

SSL only (just switched it)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or two? I see no problem at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=203. Your issue may be theme related

Comment: Just did a recent install. Vanilla Wordpress, using Shoreditch theme for admin. Working OK here